# Pass result of clicking tkinter button to another button

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I want to make a GUI where I have two buttons: from one button I can select an image and from the other button I can show the image with `cv2.imshow`. I want to use `cv2.imshow` because later I want to process the image with `cv2`. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import cv2

def select(label):
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    text = "Selected image: {}".format(filepath)
    label.config(text=text)
    return filepath

def show_image(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
label_frame.grid()
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Label")
label.grid()
func1 = lambda: select(label)
button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="select", command=func1)
button1.grid()
func2 = lambda: show_image(func1)
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="show", command=func2)
button2.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried many things, for example change `command=func2` to `command=show_image`, but nothing seems to work. I think that the image path variable in `show_image(image_path)` is a function because it is defined with lambda. Could I somehow convert the output to a string, so that the function works properly? I need to use lambda because I need to pass arguments to button command.

Comment: Suggest to use OOP design, so that instance variable can be used across class methods.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78025761/make-tkinter-button-show-image-with-cv2-imshow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the `image_path` to the `show_image` function through your `func2` lambda. When you set `func2 = lambda: show_image(func1)`, calling `func1` inside `show_image` doesn't return the `filepath` string as you might expect. Instead, it calls `select(label)` which returns the `filepath`, but then you're not using this returned `filepath` correctly as an argument to show_image. You're essentially trying to show `func1` itself, not its result.

To fix this, you can modify your approach to ensure that `func2` receives the `filepath` as a string from `select(label)` and then passes it correctly to `show_image`. You can try something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import cv2

def select(label):
    filepath = fd.askopenfilename()
    text = "Selected image: {}".format(filepath)
    label.config(text=text)
    return filepath

def show_image(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(frame)
label_frame.grid()
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Label")
label.grid()

# Use a global variable to store the selected filepath
selected_filepath = None

def update_filepath():
    global selected_filepath
    selected_filepath = select(label)

def display_image():
    global selected_filepath
    if selected_filepath:
        show_image(selected_filepath)

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="select", command=update_filepath)
button1.grid()

button2 = tk.Button(frame, text="show", command=display_image)
button2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```